# Total value sum where IDs multi

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im try get content ID , here is query...

```
$getIDs = mysql_query("SELECT content_id FROM playlist_content WHERE playlist_id=".$rrow['playlist_id']."") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getIDs)) { 
        $array[] = $row;
}
```

And here is result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 33
            [content_id] => 33
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [content_id] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [content_id] => 8
        )
)
```

Now from 2nd table with this IDs must get value
**NOTE**: ID = content_id

```
$result =  mysql_query("SELECT SUM( length ) as total FROM content WHERE ID ...
```

And echo sum of all row['length ' where is this IDs 
Need to back result just like **102** or **256** and etc...

Or there is any maybe better way to get sum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do it in a single query by joining both tables,

```
SELECT  a.content_id, SUM(b.length) TotalSum
FROM    playlist_content a
        INNER JOIN content b
            ON a.content_id = b.ID 
WHERE   a.playlist_id = IDHERE
GROUP   BY a.content_id
```

the result of the query will give you the total sum of `length` for every `content_id`.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: try to execute the query and see if it the one you are looking for.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: I think its working now
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [content_id] => 9
            [1] => 184
            [TotalSum] => 184
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 33
            [content_id] => 33
            [1] => 185
            [TotalSum] => 185
        )

)`
but how to get sum now of all this [TotalSum]  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT content_id, " .
" ( select sum (length) from content where id = content_id) as content_length " .
" FROM playlist_content " .
" WHERE playlist_id=".$rrow['playlist_id'];

$getIDs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getIDs)) { 
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Hmm and how to get result?
`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTotal);
$sum = $row['content_length'];`
Im try with this

Comment: Hmm have error FUNCTION testDatabase.sum does not exist,
testDatabase database name